# Solve differential equation solution method Bernoulli

Tags: differential

$$ \frac{y}{x}\mathrm{d}x+(y^3+\ln{x})\mathrm{d}y = 0 $$

trying to apply the bernoulli method, dividing the whole expression into $y^3$ and

$$ \frac{1}{y^2x}\mathrm{d}x+(1+\frac{\ln{x}}{y^3})\mathrm{d}y=0 $$

to replace $ z = \frac{1}{y^2}$  and at this stage, stupor. can't separate parts from dx and dy

Comment: Note that your ODE is exact equation.

Comment: @Ramanujan i don't understand. what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\underbrace{\frac{y}{x}}_{M}\mathrm{d}x+\underbrace{(y^3+\ln{x})}_{N}\mathrm{d}y = 0
$$
The differential equation is exact means that
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}
$$
Indeed
$$
\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\partial }{\partial x}(y^3+\ln{x}) = \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}
$$
It follows that there is some function $u(x,y) = const$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = M, \qquad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = N
$$
which also imlpies that the total differential of $u$ is the given differential equation
\begin{align}
du &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy \\
   &= Mdx +Ndy \\
\end{align}
The solution of it is the function $u(x,y) = const$.

Comment: this is differential equations in total differentials? I don't know how to say it better in English. possibly has a different name

Comment: I'll add sth to the answer, but you can see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation

Comment: thanks for the hint